# ExpressJS only accepts POST 6 times?

Tags: node.js, express, electron

I have an ElectronJS app to play music and I was working on a "Remote" that I can use to control my app through other devices via a browser.

I used ExpressJS and Socket.IO, but whatever I do, play, pause, next-track or previous-track, everything does work but only 6 times, i.e If I press the play-pause button 6 times, it stops working for the 7th time. Here's the code I use on the client(Remote)

```
  $('#previous').click(function () {
    $.post('/prevsong')
  })

  $('#playpause').click(function(){
    $.post('/playpause')
  })

  $('#next').click(function () {
    $.post('/nextsong')
  })
```

And this is the code I use on the ElectronJS app

```
app.post('/playpause', function () {
  // Play Pause audio tag in the Electron app
})    

app.post('/nextsong', () => {
  // Next Song Code
})

app.post('/prevsong', () => {
  // Previous Song Code
})
```

I'm new to ExpressJS and server side stuff, what am I doing wrong? How can I fix this issue?? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not a Node/Electron exprt, but, fun symptom! I wonder if you're opening a new socket every time, instead of keeping one socket open and sending messages over it (or using non-websocket requests). Apparently the per-server connection limit on the client side in Electron is 6. https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/4391

Comment: But I replaced app.post with app.get('/playback/:key') and now it works more than 6 time but it's really slow! D:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue by replacing `app.post` with `app.get`, if anyone else is experiencing the same issue, here's what I did

```
  app.get('/playback/:key', (request, response, next) => {
    response.send(request.params.key + ' button pressed');
    // Do something
  })
```

And then this on the client

```
  $('#previous').click(function () {
    $.get('/playback/prevsong')
  })

  $('#playpause').click(function(){
    $.get('/playback/playpause')
  })

  $('#next').click(function () {
    $.get('/playback/nextsong')
  })
```